# Extracting frame number, ipv6 addresses, and type information from a wireshark text file

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to extract specific information from a text file? I am trying to pull information such as the frame number, ipv6 mac addresses, and type information but I am having a rough time doing so.

Frame 1: 372 bytes on wire (2976 bits), 372 bytes captured (2976 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Example_00:aa:aa (aa:00:aa:00:aa:00), Dst: IPv4mcast_7z:zz:za (zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz)...
...
Type: IPv4 (0x0800)

I have created the class element which includes how I want the string returned. I have also opened the file using:

`''python

with open(infilename, 'r') as inputfile:

lineShark = inputfile.read()

lineStrip = lineShark.strip()

lineSplit = lineStrip.split()   ''`

I am to integrate over the lines and return every subsequent word and number inside of the document. Is there a way to search through the file and extract those elements of information from above?

I am attempting to make the returned lines look something like this:

Frame 1, Src:00:00:00:00:00:00, Dst:00:00:00:00:00:00, Type:0x0800

Very new to Python. Thank you all for your continued assistance.

Comment: Hi Franklin, could you fix the layout of the code snippet, please? Don't use the backticks for multiline snippets, but just put 4 spaces in front of each line.

What might help others to answer your question is if you give one or a few lines from a Wireshark text file as example. Also give an example of what your program should show after reading this example file. With such examples more people can help you, even people that do not know Wireshark.

If the Wireshark file contains sensitive or privacy-related information, then replace that with fake data in the example.

Comment: @gogognome I appreciate the help. I will edit my post and add what you requested.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to capture traffic to pcap file? That would be technically a better solution and you could also use existing Python libraries such as scapy, pypcapkit or python-libpcap.

Comment: @jurez I know that those solutions are there, but I am attempting to accomplish with the prerequisite that I locate that information through other means. Apologies.

Comment: One detail: The code is still not properly formatted. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to find out how you can format code in a StackOverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
import re

def read_wireshark_file(self, file_name: str):
    with open(file_name, "r") as inputfile:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(inputfile.readlines(), start=1):
            match = re.search(r"Frame (\d+)", line)
            if not match:
                print(f"Line {line_number} has no Frame.")
                break
            frame = match.group(1)

            match = re.search(r"Src:[^(]*\(([^)]*)", line)
            if not match:
                print(f"Line {line_number} has no Src.")
                break
            src = match.group(1)

            match = re.search(r"Dst:[^(]*\(([^)]*)", line)
            if not match:
                print(f"Line {line_number} has no Dst.")
                break
            dst = match.group(1)

            match = re.search(r"Type:[^(]*\(([^)]*)", line)
            if not match:
                print(f"Line {line_number} has no Type.")
                break
            type_ = match.group(1)

            print(f"Frame {frame}, Src:{src}, Dst:{dst}, Type:{type_}")
```

The module `re` stands for regular expressions. [See here for documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) This might be a little advanced for someone who just started developing Python, but it allows me to write a solution in few lines of code.

To write a solution without regular expressions, you need to write your own parser, which is probably even harder for someone who just started developing Python.

A solution with using `line.split()` might work if the input has the same number of spaces. You have to find out at which index the frame, src, dst and type are and then strip extra characters from the substring. For example, for frame, `line.split()[1]` would be `"1:"`. You have to get rid of the colon behind the `1`.

The problem of splitting is that the number of spaces might vary. For instance, `Ethernet II` is probably the name of a device on your computer. On my computer I do not have such a device, but I do have a device named `Ethernet`, which has one space less. So that would change the indexes to be used after splitting a line.